# How to make bootstrap dropdown menu width to be flexible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, I want to put several links in a drop-down menu:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
            <a id="alert" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"  href="#" title="Notification">Notifications </a>

            <ul id="noti" class="dropdown-menu">
                 {% for t in alerts%}
                   <li> 
                     <a href="/article/{{t.slug}}">{{t.title}}</a>
                   </li>
                 {% endfor %}
            </ul>     
    </li>
```

The problem is that each link has a different width, so I'm wondering how to define css to wrap even the longest links in the menu?

Answer (score 2):

I have implement snippet that you can change as per your requirement.Main part is CSS change :

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  max-width: 180px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" title="HTML">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="CSS">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="HTML CSS JavaScript bootstrap">HTML CSS JavaScript bootstrap</a></li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is good, but does not display the last link in full, which I want.

Comment: You can change value of max-width property or assign width:100% of dropdown-menu class in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="alert" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"  href="#" title="Notification">Notifications </a>

     <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: auto;">
        <ul id="noti" >
             {% for t in alerts%}
               <li> 
                 <a href="/article/{{t.slug}}">{{t.title}}</a>
               </li>
             {% endfor %}
        </ul>     
     </div>
</li>
```

All I did was put 'div' tag around 'ul'. This one worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try solution define in following link :

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/351

Comment: I tried that css. It did not work. Can you elaborate an independent answer?